# function return too early

Tags: swift, completionhandler

Can anyone explain why the completion returns empty array?

The function:

```
import Foundation

class IMBD{
    func searchMovies(searchText:String, completion: (result: [Movies]) -> Void){

        var movies = [Movies]()

        let replacedMovieTitle = searchText.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "+")
        let URLString = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=\(replacedMovieTitle)&y=&r=json"

        let URL = NSURL(string: URLString)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
            let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(URL!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
            do{

                let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
                if let search = jsonData["Search"] as? [[String : AnyObject]]{
                    for hit in search{
                        guard let title = hit["Title"] as? String else{
                              print("returna title")
                            return

                        }
                        guard let year = hit["Year"] as? String else{
                            print("returna year")
                            return
                        }
                        guard let imbdID = hit["imdbID"] as? String else{
                            print("returna imbd")
                            return
                        }
                        guard let poster = hit["Poster"] as? String else{
                            print("returna poster")
                            return
                        }
                        let movie = Movies(title: title, released: year, poster: poster, imbdID: imbdID)
                           movies.append(movie)

                    }
                }

            }catch{
            }

        }).resume()
       completion(result: movies)

    }
}
```

The call:

```
imbd.searchMovies(searchtext!, completion: { (result) -> Void in
    self.movieList = result
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to call your completion handles *inside* the `dataTaskWithURL` closure, not after it. This runs asynchronously, so if you call your `completion` outside of the closure, it would be called before the asynchronous request had a chance to retrieve anything.

Also, remember that this closure doesn't run on the main thread, so you likely want to also dispatch this to the main queue (from within the `dataTaskWithURL`).

---

For example:

```
class IMDB {
    func searchMovies(searchText:String, completion: (result: [Movie]?, error: NSError?) -> Void) -> NSURLSessionTask {
        var movies = [Movie]()
        
        let allowedCharacters = NSCharacterSet.alphanumericCharacterSet().mutableCopy() as! NSMutableCharacterSet
        allowedCharacters.addCharactersInString("-._* ")
        let replacedMovieTitle = searchText.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(allowedCharacters)!
            .stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "+")
        let URLString = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=\(replacedMovieTitle)&y=&r=json"
        
        let URL = NSURL(string: URLString)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(URL!) { data, response, error in
            guard error == nil && data != nil else {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    completion(result: nil, error: error)
                }
                return
            }
            
            do {
                let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
                if let search = jsonData["Search"] as? [[String : AnyObject]]{
                    for hit in search{
                        guard let title = hit["Title"] as? String else{
                            print("returna title")
                            continue
                        }
                        guard let year = hit["Year"] as? String else{
                            print("returna year")
                            continue
                        }
                        guard let imdbID = hit["imdbID"] as? String else{
                            print("returna imbd")
                            continue
                        }
                        guard let poster = hit["Poster"] as? String else{
                            print("returna poster")
                            continue
                        }
                        let movie = Movie(title: title, released: year, poster: poster, imdbID: imdbID)
                        movies.append(movie)
                    }
                }
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    completion(result: movies, error: nil)
                }
            } catch let error as NSError {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    completion(result: nil, error: error)
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
        
        return task
    }
}
```

A couple of other changes in the above code snippet include:

1. Add `guard` in case there was a fundamental network error (e.g. remote server down, no Internet access, etc.)
2. In the `guard` statements that are checking for `nil` values, rather than performing a `return` (in which case no further results will be gathered), you might want to just `continue` (i.e. skip to the next record). You generally see `guard` in conjunction with `return`, but in this case, `continue` is probably more appropriate.

   Frankly, you might want to take this a step further and consider whether some of these might be optional, rather than discarding the whole record. Notably, `poster` strikes me as something that might be `nil` if there was no poster available. Maybe some of the others should be optional, too, (e.g. if a movie hasn't been released yet, might it not have a release date?).
3. The occurrences of "imbd" have been replaced with "imdb".
4. The `Movies` class has been renamed to `Movie` (since each instance is a single movie, not a collection of them).
5. I changed the `completion` block to make `[Movie]` optional and to return the `NSError`. Without that, you don't have a way to differentiate between "couldn't find a title of that name" and "whoops, something went wrong".
6. When we call the `completion` closure from within the `dataTaskWithURL`, it can be very useful to have `searchMovies` dispatch `completion` calls back to the main queue, like above. This is because UI updates must always happen on the main thread, and frequently when you write routines like this, it is so you can update UI or the model with results.

   This is not always necessary to do it like this (you might want to just have this call `completion` directly from the background thread and let the routine that called `searchMovies` manually dispatch stuff to the main thread itself), but I often find it useful to have this search method just dispatch the `completion` back to the main thread and be done with it.
7. As a matter of practice, I always return the `NSURLSessionTask` when performing requests. You might not need it now, but at some future date, you might want the ability to cancel an on-going request, and having a reference to the task can be useful. It doesn't hurt to return it, and it can be useful.
8. You probably should be percent escaping the values you add to the URL. Notably the presence of `&` or `+` characters could be problematic. Note, in this case, it looks like this site isn't handling it appropriately, anyway, but it's good to get in the habit of properly percent-escaping values in a query.

   Personally, I keep this percent escaping logic in a `String` extension, but I wanted to keep this simple, so I embedded it right in this method, but hopefully it illustrates the idea.

Comment: @AsleBenjaminKinnerød - See code snippet in revised answer.

Comment: Point 6 is questionable: the decision where to run the code inside the completionhandler should be made by the caller, the receiver has no knowledge of whether the code in the completionblock should be called on any specific thread. It could be that the results are only parsed, no UI-stuff involved. In that case, no need to dispatch to the mainqueue at all. In general, users of APIs involving completionhandlers should assume the completion runs an some arbitrary thread. Dispatching should be inside the block.

Comment: I agree that you might not always want to do point 6, but 99% of the time (particularly for questions like this), people are updating models or UI in the completion blocks, so saving them from having to do their own dispatching to the main queue every time they call this is a real boon. Look at frameworks like Alamofire, which follow this same pattern. As an aside, AFNetworking had the ability to control which queue you had completion blocks running on, but Alamofire doesn't. But your point is well taken. Dispatching to the main queue isn't always necessary (but generally is useful pattern).